# Run command whenever someone joins a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to run a command automatically when a player joins the server? I need to do this without the use of a Bukkit plugin. I think it's possible with MCP but I want to know how!

Answer (score 9):

First, create a scoreboard objective of type "stat.leaveGame":

```
/scoreboard objectives add quits stat.leaveGame
```

Next, put this commands into a always active repeating command block:

```
/execute as @a[scores={quits=1..}] at @s run <COMMAND TO RUN>
```

And in a chain command block in the direction that the first command block points to:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[scores={quits=1..}] quits 0
```

The command you put in the place of `<COMMAND TO RUN>` will now run every time a player rejoins the game.

Comment: This stat is deprecated; can be replaced with `/scoreboard objectives add quits minecraft.custom:leave_game`

Comment: Also make sure that enable command blocks is true in the server.properties file

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple.
Using functions it'd look like:

Repeating command block:

```
execute as @a[tag=!Joined] run function1
```

`function1`:

```
<insert commands>
tag @s add Joined
```

## Using Command Blocks

1. Repeating, always active:

   ```
   execute as @a[tag=!Joined] run <inert command you want to run>
   ```
2. Chain, conditional:

   ```
   <commands>
   ```
3. Chain, conditional

   ```
   execute as @a[tag=!Joined] run tag @s add Joined
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is good if you want it to run the command every time they join. (i see an exploit if its a good item)

If you only want it to run the command the *first* time they join, try this:

1. Run this in the chat:

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add joined dummy
   ```
2. In command blocks on a fill clock:

   ```
   /scoreboard players add @a joined 0
   /execute @a[score_joined=0] ~ ~ ~ [command you want to run]
   ```
3. And finally, this command in a command block powered by a comparator signal from the execute command

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @a[score_joined=0] joined 1
   ```

And this will make sure that the command only runs the *first* time a player joins the server.

Comment: Or you can do this as an .mcfunction