# Minecraft - Prevent people from logging off in certain areas

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I am currently making a bukkit server. I have trade rooms, however I do not want people to be able to log off inside them, and log in while someone is trading. How can I prevent this?

My idea is to make their characters tp to spawn if they log off in the area. Anyone know a plugin where I can do this? Or how to do it if I can with WorldGuard. Thanks.

Comment: The answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/197366/83262) might point you in the right direction for running a command when a player logs in. There's no way to stop someone logging out in a specific area though (you can't stop someone force-quitting or simply turning off the power).

Answer (score 1):

You **could** run a command to teleport them out again when they recognise, but you **also** could just run a command like `/execute @e[type=Player] (x) (y) (z) /(command)` onto a NOT gate to run a command that will teleport the other player out of there... I'm thinking put the command block under the trading room, put in something like `/tp @e[type=Player,range=5] (x) (y) (z)` and make sure that no other player can come within that radius.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmmm. That may work. But I am not understanding how this detects when they log in.

Comment: I meant that I don't know how to do that. I was simply giving you another option to do sort of the same thing.