# Which command can I set so that when someone dies a /title appears?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am attempting to make a command that triggers when someone dies on my server. When someone dies, a `/title` command should run.

All the other answers I've found are for version 1.12, and I need an answer for 1.15

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command whenever someone joins a Minecraft server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197357/run-command-whenever-someone-joins-a-minecraft-server)

Comment: Oops, I apparently misread the question; the correct duplicate is [Can you use /testfor to detect the death of a player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202816/can-you-use-testfor-to-detect-the-death-of-a-player)