# Command Block should only activate if someone logs on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would I run a command block that only runs if someone logs on?

By the way, it should somehow activate another command block that has the command in it as it needs a whole command block to work

Comment: Please do not make a question or answer dependent on outside sources. Each question you ask should be self-contained and be answerable even if outside links are unavailable for whatever reason. People might be behind firewalls that block Reddit, for example.

Comment: @Nzall I've edited the post to extract question and body from Reddit post and put it into the main post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run command whenever someone joins a Minecraft server](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197357/run-command-whenever-someone-joins-a-minecraft-server)